# How to find elapsed time between two datetime values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I working in google sheets. I have already formatted datetime value and separated them in two columns. Now I want to find the time elapsed between these two dates?

date1 : 04/26/21 8:25:00 AM
date2 : 05/01/21 4:46:00 PM

What formula to use in google sheets?

Comment: … Have you tried `date2-date1`?

Comment: I tried using datedif() formula..it returns number of days.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is substract the two dates

```
=H34-G34
```

[image]

Then set the format to Number/Duration of the cell with the formula

[image]